# How to write file as it is?

Tags: php, newline

I have a string of code like this:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Now, I want to write that into a php file *just the way it is*. What I mean is that I want to write this code **with new line characters**. So the code gets stored in the above fashion. So, how can I do that?

I had tried to use file append and `fwrite`, but they write the code in one consecutive  line and what I want is to have it divided **into 3 lines**.

- On the first line - `<?php`
- On the second line - `echo "Hello world";`
- On the third line - `?>`

But I would like to do it by using only one line of code, that would be something like the below one.

```
$file = 'people.php';
// The new person to add to the file
$person = "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents to the file, 
// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: i dont get it, what is the output you are expecting? what happens instead?

Comment: What are you to trying to accomplish?

Comment: Maybe the problem lies with the editor and not with your code? Like many people say, you need a `\n` to get a new line. What editor are you using?

Comment: Are you trying to copy a PHP file into another? (if so, use [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)). [Or is it what you want to ouput the contents to the user via web?]

Comment: Hah! That is easy!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
 $File = "new.txt"; //your text file
 $handle = fopen($File, 'w');
 fwrite($handle, '<?php '."\n".' echo "Hello World "; '."\n".'?>');
 ?>
```

Comment: what if <?php
echo "Hello World";
?> this code change to <?php
$x=5;
$y=6;
$z=$x+$y;
echo $z;
?>

Comment: @SanjayRathod What Bhadra is trying to say is that you need the `\n` escaped character for a line brake in your string when you write to a file.

Comment: But i am taking this code from editor, each time code is different then how can i generate new line character? Check here http://web.guru99.com/. in this editor user can add code for execution.and obviously it is different each time so how can i insert new line character.

Comment: This bounty expires in 4 hours and you have marked this answer correct. I have a better answer. If you are online, ping here and I will put it up.

Comment: this is not a generic solution.

Answer (score 6):

This should work fine using an heredoc:

```
file_put_contents('people.php', <<<HEREDOC
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
HEREDOC
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your string should be like this

```
$str = "<?php
echo \"Hello World\";
?>";
```

then write it to any fileName.php, php while parsing ignores new lines, only semicolons matters.

*Edit 1*

Since you want to write your string as code, after following above step you will have all your code in a single line more like a compressed code, which will be not human readable, for making it human friendly, you will have to add formatting, a minimal approach for formatting will be to at least add new line chars and tabs for indentation.

for this you will have to do two things, identify chars (a) where you need to add new line feed and those chars (b) where indentation is required. Now before writing to file do some preprocessing add new line chars for char type (a) and at the same time maintain a stack for adding proper number of tabs for indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following between each line of code to put it on a new line in the php file:

```
 . PHP_EOL .
```

Answer (score 2):

You can:

```
<?php
$yourContent = <<<PHP
<?php
 echo "Hello world";
 echo "This in an example";
 $foo = 2;
 $bar = 4;
 echo "Foo + Bar = ".($foo+$bar);
?>
PHP;
file_put_contents("yourFile.php", $yourContent);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following :

```
<?php
$file = "helloworld.php";
$content = file_get_contents($file);
print_r(htmlspecialchars($content));
?>
```

**Helloworld.php** :

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

It'll work fine.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to add a line break to the end of each line. You can use a regular expression search/replace as follows (where $newData already contains the string you want to append to the file):

```
<?php
$newData = preg_replace('/$/',"\n", $newData);
file_put_contents($file, $newData, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

This finds the end of each line (indicated by $ in regex) and adds the new line (\n) at that position.

Answer (score 1):

this code is working on my pc. you will also like it.

```
<?php
$file = 'people.php';
// The new person to add to the file
$person = "<?php
echo 'Hello World';
?>\n";
// Write the contents to the file, 
// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
echo $person;
?>
```